# SOLVED: How can you set high priority on "games" permanently?

Tags: steam, monitor, system

I had question to ask, and is if there is a way to set steam games (more specifically the games themselves, that shows up as launchers or releases; example: payday2_release) in high priority permanently, or at least to set it on high priority every time i launch the game without having to manually open the system monitor.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are able of detecting your process and changing its priority using "Gnome system monitor", when you are changing a process priority you are actually changing its nice level. A nice level can be between "-20" highest priority and "19" the lowest.

so we should somehow renice (change the nice level) the game process.

You can simply use other answer suggestion and use `renice` command to do it, however there are other options too.

#### reniced

one is to use `reniced` to install it use:

```
sudo apt install reniced
```

then you can use regular expression to define rules in this file:

```
/etc/reniced.conf
```

You can add something like:

```
-20n ^game-process
```

change "game-process" with your game's process, now whenever you run `sudo reniced` it's going to renice all process defined in `/etc/reniced.conf`.

#### and

the other option is to use `and` to install it:

```
sudo apt install and
```

It's job is to activates itself in certain intervals and renices process according to their priority and CPU usage. [[read manual]](http://manpages.org/and/8)

Comment: I have a problem when trying to see the file reniced.conf, this is what terminal shows me: bash:  /etc/reniced.conf: Permission denied

Comment: You should open it using `sudo`, `sudo nano /etc/reniced.conf`

Comment: It worked! Know that im in the config, is there an exact place to put the command ( "-20n ^payday2_release" in this case) or i can put it anywhere in the config?

Comment: Follow the rules and add anything you want based on a simple regular expression like examples in file.

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

### `renice`

You can try to use `renice`, that must be run with superuser privileges in order to give it higher priority. See

```
man renice
```

for details

```
NOTES
       Users other than the superuser may only alter the priority of processes
       they own, and can only monotonically increase their ``nice value'' (for
       security reasons) within the range 0 to  19,  unless  a  nice  resource
       limit  is  set  (Linux 2.6.12 and higher).  The superuser may alter the
       priority of any process and set the priority to any value in the  range
       -20  to 19.  Useful priorities are: 19 (the affected processes will run
       only when nothing else in the system wants to), 0 (the ``base''  sched‐
       uling priority), anything negative (to make things go very fast).
```

### Examples

I don't know how the steam games are called, but the following two examples may help you set up aliases, functions or shellscripts to start the games with higher priority. Please avoid too high priority, because it can cause problems for the operating system. Maybe you can use -10 (0 is the standard priority and -20 is the highest priority).

**xterm with top**

```
xterm -e top & pid=$!;sudo renice -9 $pid
```

**htop**

```
sudo apt-get install htop   # install htop

htop & pid=$!;sudo renice -10 $pid;fg
```

### Making things convenient

You can create an alias, function or shellscript in order to make it convenient to run tasks, that you intend to run often.

**alias**

The following command will create the alias `hht` (think High priority HTop; but check first that there is no other command with the same name),

```
alias hht='htop & pid=$!;sudo renice -10 $pid;fg'
```

After that it is enough to use the short command

```
hht
```

to run `htop` with the nice value `-10`, which means high priority. Maybe it will work well with the following alias, `pd2`, to run your steam game

```
alias pd2='payday2_release & pid=$!;sudo renice -10 $pid;fg'
```

So you can test what happens, when you launch the command with the nice value `-10`,

```
pd2
```

I have not got that game, so I can not test it myself. Maybe you need to add, change or remove something to make it work as intended. Maybe you should modify the nice value.

When you have an alias that works, you can store it in the file `~/.bashrc`, your running conditions file for the bash shell. Edit the file and insert the alias line near the other aliases and save the file. After that your new alias will be available in new terminals (terminal windows), that you open.

If you need a more complicated set of commands, it might be necessary (or easier) to use a function or shellscript instead of an alias. But in this case I think it works well enough to use an alias.

Comment: Please tell me if you want help to create an alias, function or shellscript!

Comment: i used the htop option wich gives me a more simple looking than xterm with top, now im kinda lost, what im supposted to do now? and about creating an alias, how i can make an alias and what's the difference between alias, function or shellscript?

Comment: I wrote those examples to show how you can start a program and give it higher priority. What you could do, if you choose to use the method with `renice`, is the make a similar command line for each of your steam game programs. You can start with `payday2_release`, so to replace `htop` with the name of the steam game and test how it works. I will edit my answer to describe how to create an alias.

Comment: @Alexander, Is it enough with aliases, or do you want help to make special *desktop files* to start your games with high priority? Or maybe a *menu* with a line for each game? There are many possibilities ...

Comment: I already found the solution using the option reniced, i apreciate your help!

Comment: @Alexander, The solution with `reniced` is new to me too. It is a good solution. Enjoy your games, and please let us know, what nice level that works best with your games :-)